# Gmail API: send text and HTML in one mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Mail sending either text or HTML works perfectly fine, but when I send them **both** in single mail, HTML comes as an attachment named "noname.html", which contains HTML.

I have read other related questions on this topic, but couldn't find what is possibly wrong.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: sender@gmail.com
To: receiver@gmail.com
Subject: test
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="012boundary"

--012boundary
Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Hello plain text!

--012boundary
Content-type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<b>Hello html</b>
--012boundary--`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to send both HTML body and text body using gmail API. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From :

```
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="012boundary"
```

#### To :

```
Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary="012boundary"
```

#### Note :

- Using `multipart/alternative`, both parts of `Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"` and `Content-type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"` can be sent.

#### Reference :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type

In my environment, I could confirm that your request body which was modified to `multipart/alternative` worked. If this didn't work on your environment, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

In order to send a text body, a HTML body and an attachment file of HTML as one email, the structure of request body can be created as follows.

- multipart/mixed

  - multipart/alternative

    - text/plain
    - text/html
  - text/html (Attachment file)

#### Sample request body :

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: sender@gmail.com
To: receiver@gmail.com
Subject: test
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=012boundary01

--012boundary01
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=012boundary02

--012boundary02
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Hello plain text!

--012boundary02
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<b>Hello html</b>

--012boundary02--
--012boundary01
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.html"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<b>HTML sample attachment file</b>
--012boundary01--
```

#### References :

- https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html
- http://qcode.co.uk/post/70

Comment: I tried `multipart/alternative`. It has a strange effect. one thing that got fixed is that html is not coming as an attachment. but the problem is that either html or text is visible in mail not both.

Comment: in the qus above html is in the last, so html comes in mail body, if I switched the order, that means if `Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"` is in last, then text comes in mail body. it seems they are overwriting somehow

Comment: One interesting thing that i observed, that when i did "show original" in sent mail it has both html and text content.

Comment: @Khurshid I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I would like to confirm what you want. I had thought that you want to send an email as both bodies of text and HTML. But I may misunderstand about it. You want to send an email with the text body and HTML as an attachment file. Is this correct? After I could understand what you want, I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: actually I have both use cases. email as bodies of text and HTML  and text body with attachment. but none of them is working as of now.

Comment: @Khurshid Do you want to send a text body and a HTML body and a text data with an attachment file as one email? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Khurshid I'm sorry for the inconvenience because of my poor English skill. I could understand what you want. So I update my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Khurshid Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.